# Using jsonb_array_elements in sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM and trying to figure out how to produce a PostgreSQL query something along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT
    payments.*
FROM
    payments,
    jsonb_array_elements(payments.data #> '{refunds}') refunds
WHERE
    (refunds ->> 'created_at')
        BETWEEN '2018-12-01T19:30:38Z' AND '2018-12-02T19:30:38Z';
```

Though with the start date inclusive and stop date exclusive.

I've been able to get close with:

```
refundsInDB = db_session.query(Payment).\
    filter(Payment.data['refunds', 0, 'created_at'].astext >= startTime,
           Payment.data['refunds', 0, 'created_at'].astext < stopTime ).\
    all()
```

However, this only works if the refund (which is a nested array in the JSONB data) is the first element in the list of `{'refunds':[]}` whereas the SQL query above will work regardless of the position in the refund list.

After a good bit of searching it looks like there are some temporary recipes in an old [SQLAlchemy github issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3566#issuecomment-441931331), one of which talks about using `jsonb_array_elements` in a query, but I haven't been able to quite make it work in the way I'd like.

If it helps my Payment.data JSONB is exactly like the Payment object [from the Square Connect v1 API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-payments) and I am trying to search the data using the `created_at` date found in the nested `refunds` list of `refund` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Query.select_from()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from) and a [function expression alias](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.alias) to perform the query:

```
# Create a column object for referencing the `value` attribute produced by
# the set of jsonb_array_elements
val = db.column('value', type_=JSONB)

refundsInDB = db_session.query(Payment).\
    select_from(
        Payment,
        func.jsonb_array_elements(Payment.data['refunds']).alias()).\
    filter(val['created_at'].astext >= startTime,
           val['created_at'].astext < stopTime ).\
    all()
```

Note that unnesting the `jsonb` array and filtering based on it may produce multiple rows per `Payment`, but SQLAlchemy will only return distinct entities, when querying for a single entity.